# S3FS: Allowing permission for specific user or group

Tags: unix, amazon-s3, mount, s3fs

I would like to mount filesystem with s3 bucket using S3FS.

I want, that different users from specific group have access to the mounted folder and can read/write access.

When I use "allow_other" option, all users have full access to the mounted folder. For example:

```
s3fs bucket-name /home/folder-name/ -o passwd_file=./.passwd-s3fs -o allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1001
```

But I need, that only users from specific group have access to the mounted folder (not all users).

Is it possible?

Comment: `chown`/`chgrp` and `chmod`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [goofys](https://github.com/kahing/goofys) with the --gid option.